# OpenCV draw histogram with axis labels and coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I read the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) regarding how to draw histograms and I've adapted the code in the tutorial to my needs, so that the output is a bar histogram like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to add axis with labels and indexes. Is there any painless solution to achieve this?

Comment: First show what you have tried then if you encounter problem then we will help you. We are not here to give you ready made solutions.

Comment: You can try adapt Gnuplot http://www.gnuplot.info/ , but it not so painless.

Comment: @user2481422 I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not asking for a ready made solution. As I said, I adapted the code to plot the data I need and instead of lines I draw rectangles. What I expect is an answer telling me to check some api call that I've missed and that adds axis data.. or how to workaround this. I have my code and don't need yours.

Comment: You can check gnuplot C++ api here: http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/

Comment: @AndreySmorodov thanks, I'm looking at it! I preferred not using another library but apparently opencv lacks of such feature

Answer (score 0):

In case you still needed a solution and you don't mind to use gnuplot.

Here is an example that I read a color image, turn it to gray, calculate the histogram and then draw the histogram.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if (!image.data)
    {
        LOGMSG_ERR_S_C() << "No image data\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // construct a grayscale histogram
    int binNumber = 256;
    int channels[] = {0};
    int numImages = 1;
    int histDim = 1;
    int histSize[] = {binNumber};
    float grayRange[] = {0, 256};
    const float* ranges[] = {grayRange};
    cv::MatND hist;
    cv::calcHist(&image, numImages, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, histDim, histSize, ranges);

    // plot the historgram
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > data;
    for (int bin = 0; bin < binNumber; bin++)
    {
        data.emplace_back(bin, hist.at<float>(bin));
    }
    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "plot" << gp.file1d(data) << "with lines title 'hist'" << std::endl;
    cv::imshow("gray", image);

    // show the image and wait for a keypress
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

You may need to use boost for `#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"`

CMakeLists.txt

```
# Handle Boost
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system iostreams filesystem REQUIRED) # gnuplot needed: system iostreams filesystem

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${targetName}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```